# How do I stop automatic updates in Windows 10 home?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've been searching the web and all I can come up with is workarounds or disabling the update service completely.  You used to be able to choose download but don't install or let me decide.  I don't like updates before I have a chance to read up on possible bugs.  I have a few friends who have issues with recent updates.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the automatic update can not be disable in Win 10 now.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't turn them off**, that's the feature of Windows 10 to be up to date. But there are some ways how to slow them down because of possible bugs:

> Open Windows 10's Settings app and select Update & Security > Windows
>   Update > Advanced Options and scroll down to "Choose when updates are
>   installed." Click the drop-down and change it from Semi-Annual Channel
>   (Targeted) to Semi-Annual Channel.

Keep in mind that this options also differs from the version of Windows (Home / Pro / Enterprise / Educational).

Comment: The question specifically states Windows 10 Home, and the approach you quoted doesn't work there, as there is no "Choose when updates are installed" option.